# Wordpress echo src for category image

Tags: php, wordpress, categories

I have added the ability to add featured images to post categories using a plugin called WP Custom Categories. I am trying to display a list of categories from a custom post type on a page but instead of displaying the title, I want to show the image.

To do this I have created a custom walker class for the Walker_Category which is changing the output of wp_list_categories.

My custom walker class looks like this in functions.php:

```
class WPQuestions_Walker extends Walker_Category {

function start_lvl(&$output, $depth=1, $args=array()) {  
    $output .= "\n<ul class=\"product_cats\">\n";  
}  

function end_lvl(&$output, $depth=0, $args=array()) {  
    $output .= "</ul>\n";  
}  

function start_el(&$output, $item, $depth=0, $args=array()) {
    // Category image
    if ( is_category() && function_exists('category_image_src')) {
$category_image = category_image_src( array( 'size' => 'full' ) , false );
} else {
$category_image = '';
} 

    //$output .= "<li class=\"item\">".esc_attr( $item->name );
    $output .= "<div class=\"col-md-4 entry project\">";
    $output .= "<img class=\"project_cat_image\" src=\"";
    $output .= $category_image;
    $output .= "\"/>";
}  

function end_el(&$output, $item, $depth=0, $args=array()) {  
    //$output .= "</li>\n";
    $output .= "</div>";
}      

}
```

You will see the snippet of code I am using to try and grab the image is as follows:

```
// Category image
    if ( is_category() && function_exists('category_image_src')) {
$category_image = category_image_src( array( 'size' => 'full' ) , false );
} else {
$category_image = '';
}
```

However, no URL is being outputted in my html. What am I doing wrong here? Is there a better way to try and grab this image?

Comment: Found a possible: Try this: `$image_src = category_image_src( array('size'=>array(300,200) ) , false );` or `$image = category_image( array('size'=>array(300,200) ) , false );` from https://wordpress.org/support/topic/params-example

Comment: You're following this example? http://premium.wpmudev.org/blog/how-to-add-feature-images-to-your-wordpress-categories/?nlv=c&utm_expid=3606929-32.jVSGECWYSiWZJXI3ODEEGA.2&utm_referrer=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.com%2Furl%3Fsa%3Dt%26rct%3Dj%26q%3D%26esrc%3Ds%26source%3Dweb%26cd%3D2%26ved%3D0CCYQFjAB%26url%3Dhttp%253A%252F%252Fpremium.wpmudev.org%252Fblog%252Fhow-to-add-feature-images-to-your-wordpress-categories%252F%26ei%3DdytSVbnbD9e5oQTGq4GQAg%26usg%3DAFQjCNFtck5fdmgzXXPlGnZ1zQHyKBCAOg%26sig2%3DRcn5CXTruTDEYHB2Lt3grQ

Comment: Hey @Twisty Yes I am, Where in my code do I put this?

Comment: This will be in a specific theme file. The example goes through that for the 'twenty twelve' theme. What theme are you using?

Comment: My own theme, I've added it into my functions.php file in my custom walker, however, it's not really a change from what was already written - it's just changing the name of the parameter, so I still have the same issue